# How can I keep my deployment development and library development separated?

Tags: git, deployment, version-control, openshift

So I want to deploy to a cloud computing provider that uses git hooks to execute deployment. In particular, I want to use Openshift, but I think this question is generic enough to apply to other providers.

In effect, I've got two parallel projects happening at the same time: one that performs piles of computations on inputs, and a web-facing project that bundles the outputs of that library and presents a nice interface, etc. The two are separate, and development on one does not necessarily imply a change in another.

My question is this, then: I *could* dump the library repository into the libs/ section of the deployment repo, but that would be ugly, and any distribution of the library would entail dragging around a pile of unneeded cruft in the form of this deployment code.

Any advice or experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules), or a packaged SDK for your library code.  Both let you independently develop both projects, and upgrading of the library to the parent project is on your schedule.